# I can not upload a trasparent logo in wordpress site log

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, transparency, graphical-logo

Wordpress site logo is not transparent

[image]

When i upload a transparent logo in wordpress site it is not transparent, as you can see the grey dots behind that apple logo, what is that problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the logo a PNG format? WIthout seeing the file, my guess is you searched for a 'transparent apple logo' and tried using an image that is not ACTUALLY transparent. Oftentimes web searches for transparent logos will (for whatever reason) give you images that use the gray grid to look transparent, when in fact they're actually part of the image.

Comment: yes it was a png format but you are right i have searched for transparent logo in google search so i guess it was not transparent at all like you said.